# Automapper mapping collection of enums into view model collection

Tags: c#, automapper

- AutoMapper 5.3.0 alpha (Yet to upgrade to the latest and greatest)

I have a DTO as follows:

```
public class AoACrudFieldValuesGdataHealthInput
{
    public AoACrudFieldValuesGdataHealthInput()
    {
       PrevHealthAssessment = new HashSet<HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum>();
    }

    public HashSet<HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum> PrevHealthAssessment { get; set; }
}
```

and a EF POCO of:

```
[Table("Health", Schema = "gdata")]
public class GdataHealthTableModel : AuditedEntity
{
    public GdataHealthTableModel()
    {
        //PrevHealthAssessment = new HashSet<HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum>();
    }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public ICollection<GdataHealthPrevAssesmentTableModel> PrevHealthAssessment { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
[Table("HealthPrevAssesment", Schema = "gdata")]
public class GdataHealthPrevAssesmentTableModel : AuditedEntity
{
    public HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum Assessment { get; set; }
}
```

I need help extending my map:

```
CreateMap<AoACrudFieldValuesGdataHealthInput, GdataHealthTableModel>();
```

such that AoACrudFieldValuesGdataHealthInput.PrevHealthAssessment ends up in GdataHealthTableModel.PrevHealthAssessment. Currently I get an error as my CreateMap() is not detailed enough - naturally.

Is this possible? Or do I get the mapper to ignore that field and do it by hand?

NOTE: For both EF POCO's I have omitted the Id field which is an auto increment for sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Define an additional map for `HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum` -> `GdataHealthPrevAssesmentTableModel`:

```
CreateMap<AoACrudFieldValuesGdataHealthInput, GdataHealthTableModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.PrevHealthAssessment, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.PrevHealthAssessment));

CreateMap<HealthPrevHealthAssessmentEnum, GdataHealthPrevAssesmentTableModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, o => o.Ignore()) // auto ID
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Assessment , o => o.MapFrom(src => src));
```

Not sure of AutoMapper can convert an ICollection to a HashSet out of the box, I think it can.